# dvips: warning: no config file for `amz'

Tags: fonts, verbatim, computer-modern, dvips, type1

I have submitted a PDF manuscript to a conference and I get the feedback that my fonts in the verbatim environment either look hideous or they are not rendered at all. The manuscript looks nice on my machine.

I guess this is caused by the Type 3 fonts.

[Using Computer Modern Type 1 Fonts with Dvips](http://frank.harvard.edu/~coldwell/tetexps.html)

And indeed, I get the following warnings when generating the pdf file from the dvi:

```
dvips: warning: no config file for `amz'
dvips: warning: no config file for `cmz'
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**What should I do now? How can I get rid of the Type 3 fonts?**

---

As for a minimal example: since I cannot reproduce this issue on my machine I have no chance to give you a reproducable example.

My attempt would be to put some text into the verbatim environment.

This is the relevant line from the bash script generating the PDF file:

`exec dvips -Ppdf -Pamz -Pcmz -j0 -q -f $infile | gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outfile -sPAPERSIZE=a4 $OPTIONS -c save pop`

You can see the flags passed to dvips.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of code and how you're generating your document?

Comment: I added some details to the question. I cannot give you an example since I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine.

Comment: That's a very old way of doing. The configuration files `config.amz` and `config.cmz` have long been removed from TeX Live. `exec dvips -f $infile | ps2pdf - $outfile` should do. But of course using `pdflatex` is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed TeX with the Ubuntu package manager you have at least the 2009 version.

Calls such as

```
dvips -Ppdf -Pamz -Pcmz -j0 -q
```

are obsolete since quite a long time; the files `config.amz` and `config.cmz` have been removed long ago.

You can do the conversion in a much simpler way:

```
exec dvips -q -f $infile | ps2pdf - $outfile
```

as `dvips` and `ps2pdf` will take care of all the font business.

However, I recommend to compile your document with `pdflatex` that frees you from all those burdens and directly produces a PDF file, if you don't need PSTricks in your document.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! A colleague of mine tried pdflatex (I don't know the details what and how) but the resulting pdf still contained Type 3 fonts. In this case I could use `pdflatex` but in most cases I am forced to use `latex` unfortunately. I will try your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: OK, your command generated the right thing: the PDF file contains only Type 1 and 1C fonts. Thanks! :)